# Triggering Buttons named similarly in multiple Partial Views JQuery MVC 3 Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, button

I'm having a problem with accessing my buttons separately using jquery.
Suppose I have the following code:

```
<button id="ButtonOne">Button One</button>
<button id="ButtonTwo">Button Two</button>
<br />
<button id="ButtonThree">Button Three</button>
```

This is rendered in a partial view that gets posted up to four times in the same main view and grouped based on

```
@Model.Group.ToString()
```

What I want to do is be able to use jQuery to use one of my buttons for an event, but everything I've tried so far either doesn't work or activates all the buttons with the same name. I've been trying to figure out how to identify each button individually based on which group it is in. The code below is the code that fires off every button on the page instead of just the one I want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ButtonOne').click(function () {
            alert('Button One was clicked.');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Obviously this is because they all have the same name, but is there any way that I can do something similar to this:

```
<button id="ButtonOne" + @Model.Group.ToString()>ButtonOne</button>
```

Comment: It is imperative that your buttons have unique id attributes. Html containing multiple elements with the same id is not valid.

Comment: I know that, which is why if you read the entire post I explained that I knew that and just needed a way to do the last code on the page properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ids should be unique within a document, so your duplicate Ids will be what's causing your problem. Could you do something like this -

```
<button id="ButtonOne@(Model.Group.ToString())">ButtonOne</button>
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work because it just sets the button's id to "ButtonOne@Model.Group.ToString()" because there is no space the @ symbol just becomes part of the string and doesn't effect how the string is rendered.
I ended up using String.Format() which worked.

Comment: Sorry - I'd missed the parentheses - answer updated. It should work now.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks. Looks way better than using string.Format() too.